# Cannot install Ubuntu on HP Pavilion p6120t - installer complains of insufficient space and GParted says "no devices found"

Tags: system-installation, gparted, disk-usage

I have a HP Pavilion p6120t desktop and I recently wiped its hard drive using my Macbook's disk utility.

I was unable to install Ubuntu on it because I apparently don't have 4.4GB of space available. I tried using GParted, but I got "no devices found".

What should I do?

Comment: Please give more info about your system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much info about your system, so this is all I can provide currently:

Please, before opening the installer, open Terminal by searching for it and type `sudo apt-get remove dmraid`, then press Enter. Let the process finish and then try opening the installer.